# Intervalley scattering in graphene in presence of impurities

Tags: condensed-matter, fourier-transform, dirac-equation, graphene

A long range impurity like coulomb impurity does not induce an inter valley scattering between the two Dirac points. Is there any mathematical explanation for the same although this is explained by looking at the Fourier space representation of the impurity potential. Is there a deeper mathematical reason?